# What's the difference between NSLocaleCollationIdentifier and NSLocaleCollatorIdentifier?

Tags: ios, nslocale

From the doc:

> **NSLocaleCollationIdentifier**
>
> The key for the collation associated with the locale.
>
> The corresponding value is an NSString object; for example, "pinyin".
>
> **NSLocaleCollatorIdentifier**
>
> The key for the collation identifier for the locale.
>
> The corresponding value is an NSString object; for example, "en".

I don't understand the difference between "collation associated with the locale" and "collation identifier for the locale".